# Gisgraphy importer crashing, possibly due to JDBC connections problem. Is there a fix?

Tags: postgresql, import, reverse-geocoding, jetty, gisgraphy

I've been trying to install gisgraphy for the past few days. The setup has went well, but the software crashes while importing data. I'm only importing data for a single country so it's not overly time consuming to retry.

I was searching through the logs and found this error, which occurs at least twice, but not at the point of crash (the log just stops at crash)

```
WARN [btpool0-3] UserSuppliedConnectionProvider | No connection properties specified - the user must supply JDBC connections
ERROR [btpool0-3] SchemaExport | schema export unsuccessful
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection
        at org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.java:30)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:28)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.drop(SchemaExport.java:143)
        at com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper.createSqlSchemaFile(DatabaseHelper.java:154)
        at com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper.generateSQLDropSchemaFile(DatabaseHelper.java:130)
        at com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper.generateSqlDropSchemaFileToRerunImport(DatabaseHelper.java:177)
        at com.gisgraphy.importer.ImporterManager.resetImport(ImporterManager.java:245)
        at com.gisgraphy.webapp.action.ResetImportAction.reset(ResetImportAction.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
        at com.gisgraphy.webapp.interceptor.UserRoleAuthorizationInterceptor.intercept(UserRoleAuthorizationInterceptor.java:65)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at com.gisgraphy.webapp.filter.StaticFilter.doFilterInternal(StaticFilter.java:155)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilterWithoutSession.parsePage(PageFilterWithoutSession.java:172)
        at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilterWithoutSession.doFilter(PageFilterWithoutSession.java:92)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:164)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:406)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at com.gisgraphy.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:233)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
        at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
        at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1089)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:365)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:211)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:285)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:502)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:821)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:208)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:378)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:226)
        at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
```

I've already researched this issue and found it's usually attributed to misformatted jdbc properties, however my jdbc.properties file appears to be properly formatted:

```
###############################################################################
#   Gisgraphy Project
#
#   This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
#   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
#   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#   This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
#   Lesser General Public License for more details.
#
#   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
#   License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
#   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA
#
#  Copyright 2008  Gisgraphy project
#  David Masclet <davidmasclet@gisgraphy.com>
#
#
###############################################################################
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/gisgraphy
jdbc.username=[ommitted]
jdbc.password=[ommitted]

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernatespatial.postgis.PostgisDialectNG

# Needed by Hibernate3 Maven Plugin defined in pom.xml
hibernate.connection.username=[ommitted]
hibernate.connection.password=[ommitted]
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/gisgraphy
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Are there other resolutions for this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be a database issue, not a GIS-centric one.  As a new user, please be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Geographic Information Systems is a question and answer site for people interested in GIS, Remote Sensing, Photogrammetry, Geodesy and Surveying, _**as well as Programming/Databases specific to the aforementioned.**_ 

I apologize if it's in the wrong section though. Gisgraphy is a GIS software/ database solution.